# How to change polling sequence on ACR122U / PN532

Tags: nfc, contactless-smartcard, emv, acr122

I'm looking to develop a Go application to read EMV and NFC cards with a 2 separate custom wakeup frames.

My polling loop should check WUPA, then WUPB, then WUPCUST1, then WUPCUST2.  Both custom frames follow the same protocol as Type-A

At the end of the loop, it should return which (if any) of the four it has found (in normal cases, it would be 1 or 2 of the four E.g. Type-A & Custom 1).

I have been trying to configure this by with pseudo-ADPU commands to the PN532 chip, but I'm struggling to understand the [documentation](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/141520.pdf), which is very technical and contains many unreferenced terms and acronyms.

I can successfully call `InJumpForDEP`, `InJumpForPSL`, `InListPassiveTarget`, but get a 0x27 error () when I try to call `InATR` with `[]byte{0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0xD4, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00}` or `[]byte{0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0xD4, 0x50, 0x01, 0x00}`.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of NFC hardware isn't deep enough to figure out what calls I need to make to the PN532 to configure this.  Or indeed, if what I am trying to achieve is even possible.